# Select xfce4 desktop environment with autologin in Ubuntu 14.04.03 LTS

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, xfce

I am trying to select xfce desktop environment upon boot up with autologin enabled. I created a config file in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/50-myconfig.conf` with the settings as below:

```
[SeatDefaults]
user-session=xfce
autologin-user=user
autologin-user-timeout=0
autologin-session=xfce
```

But only the autologin takes effect, but not choosing the session. It will login into unity desktop environment.

However, if I try this on **Ubuntu 15.10 Wily Werewolf**, it works flawlessly.

FYI, these are the things that I have tried but doesn't seem to have any effect

1. Set `Session=xfce` in `~/.drmc`
2. Modify `ubuntu.desktop` to start `startxfce4`, and even remove it temporarily from `/usr/share/xsession`

BTW. My `lightdm` version in `Ubuntu 14.04.03` is `1.10.5`, while `Ubuntu 15.10` is `1.16.4`

Comment: Why don't you try updating your `lightdm`

Comment: @dattutbrus I did try but it would say its already the latest. Doing `apt-get install --reinstall` would install the same version again.

Comment: Then check if you have already installed all the XFCE desktop thingy. Also, check the autostart. If nothing's paranormal, try other display manager like `gdm` or try to turn off Autologin.